# Higher derivatives of $g(s,t)=f\left(se^t, s\right)$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Let $$g(s,t) = f(se^t,s).$$
Fill in the blanks with functions of s and t:
$$g_{ss} (s,t) = ------------- f_{x}(se^t,s) +$$
$$-------------- f_{y}(se^t,s) +$$
$$-------------- f_{xx}(se^t,s) +$$
$$-------------- f_{xy}(se^t,s) +$$
$$-------------- f_{yy}(se^t,s) +$$

This was a midterm question which I only got 1/5 on. I got the first blank as $$e^t$$ because $$\frac{\partial \:g}{\partial \:s}= \frac{\partial \:f}{\partial \:x}*\frac{\partial \:x}{\partial \:s}+\frac{\partial \:f}{\partial \:y}*\frac{\partial \:y}{\partial \:s},  where \frac{\partial}{\partial \:s}(se^t) = e^t.$$
I thought that the partial of y with respec tot s would = 1 but it was apparently wrong.
How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating once, we have

$$ g_s(s,t) = e^t f_x(se^t,s) + f_y(se^t,s). $$

Differentiating this again with respect to $s$ and using the chain rule, we get

$$ g_ss(s,t) = e^{2t} f_{xx}(se^t,s) + e^t f_{yx}(se^t,s) + e^tf_{xy}(se^t,s) + f_{yy}(se^t,s) = \\
e^{2t}f_{xx}(se^t,s) + 2e^t f_{xy}(se^t,s) + f_{yy}(se^t,s) $$

(assuming that $f$ is nice enough so that the second partial derivatives commute). In particular, the first two blanks should be filled with zeroes.

Comment: How did you get the $$e^{2t}?$$

Comment: When you differentiate $e^t f_x(se^t,s)$ with respect to $s$, you get $e^t \left( e^t f_{xx}(se^t, s) + f_{yx}(se^t,s) \right)$ and $e^t \cdot e^t = e^{2t}$.